# Angular 4: 'Property 'includes' is missing in type' for custom data type

Tags: angular, typescript, types, model, bundle

I'm seeing the error:

```
/root/simutronx/simutron-app/src/app/app.component.ts (45,5): Type
'Promise<OneDSlider[]>' is not assignable to type 'OneDSlider[]'. Property
'includes' is missing in type 'Promise<OneDSlider[]>'.
```

And this in the console:

```
/root/simutronx/simutron-app/src/app/mock-simutronx.ts (5,64): 
Type '{ id:    number; name: string; value: number; quantity: number; }[]'
is not assignable to type 'OneDSlider[]'.
Type '{ id: number; name: string; value: number; quantity: number; }' is
not assignable to type 'OneDSlider'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'quantity' does not
exist in type 'OneDSlider'.  vendor.bundle.js:29679:4
```

After creating a data service. Model (simutronx.ts):

```
export class OneDSlider {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  value: number;
  quantity: number;
}
```

As you can see above the quantity property is there on the data model. (This didn't contain a quantity property before it does now, and I have restarted the server process since).

Data service (simutronx.service.ts):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { OneDSlider, TwoDSlider, Switch, Output } from './simutronx';
import { ONEDSLIDERS, TWODSLIDERS, SWITCHES, OUTPUTS } from './mock-simutronx';

@Injectable()
export class SimXService {
  getOneDSliders(): Promise<OneDSlider[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(ONEDSLIDERS);
  }
  getTwoDSliders(): Promise<TwoDSlider[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(TWODSLIDERS);
  }
  getSwitches(): Promise<Switch[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(SWITCHES);
  }
  getOutputs(): Promise<Output[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(OUTPUTS);
  }
}
```

Mock data (mock-simutronx.ts):

```
import { UIConstructor, OneDSlider, TwoDSlider, Switch, Output } from './simutronx';

export const ONEDSLIDERS: OneDSlider[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Shipping Container Purchase Cost', value: 7, quantity: 9 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Container Rental Costs', value: 99, quantity: 15 }
];

export const TWODSLIDERS: TwoDSlider[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Available Shipping Containers', max_value: 99, min_value: 0, quantity: 3 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Purchasing Staff Available', max_value: 82, min_value: 0, quantity: 5 }
];

export const SWITCHES: Switch[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Min/Max', state: true }
];

export const OUTPUTS: Output[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Profit', value: 1000 }
];
```

And my app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { UIConstructor, OneDSlider, TwoDSlider, Switch, Output } from './simutronx';
import { ONEDSLIDERS, TWODSLIDERS, SWITCHES, OUTPUTS } from './mock-simutronx';
import { SimXService } from './simutronx.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [SimXService]
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'SimutronX';
  onedsliders = ONEDSLIDERS;
  twodsliders = TWODSLIDERS;
  switches = SWITCHES;
  outputs = OUTPUTS;
  valuesinput = false;
  simXcreated = false;

  constructor(private simXService: SimXService) { }

  coefficients: UIConstructor = {
    id: 1,
    title: 'coefficients',
    value: 2
  }
  constraints: UIConstructor = {
    id: 1,
    title: 'constraints',
    value: 2
  }

  inputNums(): void {
    this.valuesinput = true;
  }

  createSimX(): void {
    this.simXcreated = true;
  }

  getOneDSliders(): void {
    this.onedsliders = this.simXService.getOneDSliders();
  }
  getTwoDSliders(): void {
    this.twodsliders = this.simXService.getTwoDSliders();
  }

}
```

I have searched and found this similar question: [Angular 4 Error : Property 'includes' is missing in type '() => any'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483848/angular-4-error-property-includes-is-missing-in-type-any) but though the error message is similar, the cause of the problem does not appear to be the same. I have also double-checked the data types and it does seem that the model and the mock data are the same...

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is in the error. You are trying to assign something of type **Promise< OneDSlider[]>** to something of type **OneDSlider** at this line `this.onedsliders = this.simXService.getOneDSliders();`

You can either not return a promise from the **SimXService** or have the **AppComponent** wait for the promise to resolve to retrieve the value.

```js
getOneDSliders(): void {
  this.simXService.getOneDSliders()
    .then(sliders => {
      this.onedsliders = sliders;
    });
}
```

Comment: The error message specifies: `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'quantity' does not
exist in type 'OneDSlider'.  vendor.bundle.js:29679:4` which does not seem to make sense given your answer. Also, this is the exact same data format specified on the Angular Tour of Heroes tutorial: `export class HeroService {
  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
  }` I'll try your code and see if it works though...

Comment: Ah, does work! Thanks for the help. I'd have just sat there trying to figure out why it wasn't seeing the quantity property.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error message when trying to return a Promise:

```
  ERROR in /GitHub/Angular/skillwise-accounts-app/src/app/app.component.ts (22,5): Type 'Promise<Account[]>' is not assignable totype 'Account[]'.
  Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Promise<Account[]>'.
```

After looking at [ES7 Array.prototype.includes() missing in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2340), it seems like my typescript configuration was missing something.
To fix my error, I ended up needing to update my project tsconfig.json file. I added the following to the `compilerOptions`:

```
    "lib": ["dom", "es2017"],
```

Hope this helps.